# Mongo sort descending

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having trouble sorting in descending order with mongo.

Example:
I have multiple entries with the field score.

```
{_id:1, score:0}
{_id:2, score:1}
{_id:3, score:-1}
```

When i run the following command

```
db.entries.find({}).sort({score:-1});
```

It ranks in the following order:

```
{_id:2, score:1}
{_id:3, score:-1}
{_id:1, score:0}
```

Any idea why this is happening, and is there any fix?

Comment: which version of mongo are you using? It returns correct result in my mongo.I am using 2.4.6 version.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Nevermind i've found the bug, i was storing the scores as Strings, which was causing the error.

Comment: So it would be nice to accept the answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
db.entries.find().sort({score:-1})
```

instead of

```
db.entries.find({}).sort({score:-1})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if your scenario is to sort in general without any specific field

`db.entries.find({}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).pretty();`

I have added limit, assuming you are only interested in the latest entry, however you can change accordingly